# "This Update is not applicable to your system"

Tags: powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

When trying to install Windows Management Framework 5 on Windows 8.1 I'm getting this error: `"This Update is not applicable to your system"`.

According to this [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/getting-powershell-5-running-windows-7-server-2008-r2-darwin-sanoy) it's due to a dependency on PS 4 not being present however as you'll see it's there.

[image: PowerShell Version 4.0]

I've tried installing via chocolatey but that also fails `"Running wusa.exe with ... was not successful. Exit code was '-2145124329'`. The log file says `Windows update  could not be installed because of error 2149842967`.

Anyone seen this before and know of a workaround?

Comment: can you install any other `.msu` file?

Comment: A bunch of windows updates installed recently. I'm an administrator on the machine.